# JavaScript not returning Google Sheets Cell Value

Tags: javascript, variables, google-sheets

In this code I have declared a variable to get cell value from some spreadsheet owned by me.

And then I used that variable for innerHtml of

element with id "value".

But the web page is not showing any result.

It gives blank page ..

Any idea, what where went wrong ..?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Getting Values from Sheets</title>
</head>
<body>


<p id="value2">Hello World</p>

<p id="value"></p>

<script src="sheets/snippets/snippets.js">

gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId: 1jH0y-PknkZXH7KqjPBWDv98kkBnndGt_GIbdUh_1nRM,
  range: Users!A2
}).then((response) => {
  var result = response.result;
  var numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
  console.log(`${numRows} rows retrieved.`);
document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = result;
});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: why are you not setting the innerHTML where you do the console.log????

Comment: I don't know how to do brother ,

Comment: May I jump that innerHtml line to below to console.log line ...?

Answer (score 1):

Set the value at the time of receiving the response.

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId: 1jH0y-PknkZXH7KqjPBWDv98kkBnndGt_GIbdUh_1nRM,
  range: users!a2
}).then((response) => {
  var result = response.result;
  var numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
  console.log(`${numRows} rows retrieved.`);
  document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = result;
});
```

This is because the next task is executed after sending a request to perform an asynchronous task.

`document.getElementById("value").innerHTML = result;` code was outside of `then()`.

The `var result` is not defined at this moment.

Comment: What should be the spreadsheet sharing setting ? May I put it to Restricted , or it should be "view only to others" or be "published" ..?

Comment: @PRATAPKUMARKOTTI I don't know what it means. For the new problem, it would be better to post a new question.

Comment: I'm new to javascript, could you modify the code for me ?

Comment: @PRATAPKUMARKOTTI No clues have been found in this post to solve the problem about "spreadsheet sharing".

Comment: I mean to retrieve the data from sheet, is it to be shared to public to "view only" ? Or may I put it default "only Me" ?

Comment: @PRATAPKUMARKOTTI The authority to disclose will vary depending on the purpose. If you're not the only one who's going to use it, set it to view only.

Comment: <script src="sheets/snippets/snippets.js">

I modified this line, 
still I'm getting the value to that <p> element

Comment: @PRATAPKUMARKOTTI What is your goal now? The question is ambiguous. I don't know what you want to get.

Comment: my goal is to get the cell (Users!A2) value , and want to declare that to a variable. thanks